# Author affiliation like in SDM

Tags: authblk

I am using this template for SDM paper http://www.siam.org/proceedings/macros/soda2e.all.

I have multiple authors with some authors from the same institutions. How can I show this information in the authors section. The sample file shows different authors from different institution

```
\author{Corey Gray\thanks{Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics.} \\
\and 
Tricia Manning\thanks{Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics.}}
```

I want Corey Grat and Tricial Manning to have same sign * and Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics to be shown only once

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Comment: Well, you should include the right institution in each case with the macr `\thanks{}` as in the example. Please add the MWE for see what are you doing.

Comment: @Aradnix. I have added some sample. It is now what I wanted

Comment: Please read the lik above, in this site we ask for **full** minimal working examples for can run them on our PCs or Macs and can detect easily the error. So, please ad a MWE and not only a snippet. BTW that example creates you an error or what's the problem?

Comment: @Aradnix. Look at this one http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/ml/papers/acharya.sdm14.pdf. I want to have the author index like this one

Comment: @Aradnix Any ideas? I have been searching for it for a while but couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 2):

Well, to answer your question I will use the code example of the class you mention in your question:

```
\documentclass[twoside,leqno,twocolumn]{article}  
\usepackage{ltexpprt} 

\begin{document}


%\setcounter{chapter}{2} % If you are doing your chapter as chapter one,
%\setcounter{section}{3} % comment these two lines out.

\title{\Large SIAM/ACM Preprint Series Macros for
Use With LaTeX\thanks{Supported by GSF grants ABC123, DEF456, and GHI789.}}
\author{Corey Gray\thanks{Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics.} \\
\and 
Tricia Manning\footnotemark[2]} %{Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics.}}
\date{}

\maketitle


%\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\setcounter{page}{1}%Leave this line commented out.

\begin{abstract} \small\baselineskip=9pt This is the text of my abstract. It is a brief
description of my
paper, outlining the purposes and goals I am trying to address.\end{abstract}




\section{Problem Specification.}In this paper, we consider the solution of the $N \times
N$ linear
system
\begin{equation} \label{e1.1}
A x = b
\end{equation}
where $A$ is large, sparse, symmetric, and positive definite.  We consider
the direct solution of (\ref{e1.1}) by means of general sparse Gaussian
elimination.  In such a procedure, we find a permutation matrix $P$, and
compute the decomposition
\[
P A P^{t} = L D L^{t}
\]
where $L$ is unit lower triangular and $D$ is diagonal.
.
.
. 
etc.
\end{document}
```

In fact, the trick is very easy, we only need to use the `\footnotemark[<number>]`command. This introduces the reference `<number>` in a footnote *but* **without compose the footnote**.

In other words, according to the lines of the snippet of your question, for you can use the same symbol to name several authors from the same institution use:

```
\author{Corey Gray\thanks{Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics.} \\
\and 
Tricia Manning\footnotemark[2]}
```

Instead of repeat the command `\thanks` with its content, you'll use `\footnotemark[]`. The reason of the number `2` is because if you choose `1`, that footnote will have the same symbol than the first `\thanks` in the title.

As you can see, the trick is to know the number (order of appearance) of the note (and its symbol) you want to repeat to display as you want them.